# Why is OpenCV retrivieng this error in the middle of a video processing? error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, mkv

I am using openCV to process a video capture (.mkv file) with python2

```
import cv2
(....)

videofile = 'a.mkv'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videofile)
(....)
t_frames, fps, t_time, w, h = getVideoInfo(cap)
(....)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES ,first_frame)
(....)
frame = 0
while (not stopped==1):
    ret, frame = cap.read(frame)
    (...some functions related with cv2 are here called...)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (...)
```

However at almost the end of the video processing some erros appear:
error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

And the error occurs at cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Any idea? A bad frame? However I called before some functions related with the cv2 and it was ok.

Comment: `ret, frame = cap.read(frame)` -- test `ret` to make sure the `read` succeeds. When it fails (which would happen once there are no more frames left to read), don't pass `frame` (which in that case holds the value of `None`) to other functions which expect an actual image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After load a resource check if the resource was loaded properly.

```
ret, frame = cap.read(frame)
(....)
if frame is not None
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```